# Is CORBA of JBoss OpenJDK ORB same as in JDK

Tags: java, glassfish, corba, orb

We are planning on migrating from JDK7 to JDK17. It seems there are two possible alternative for CORBA:

```
(1) GlassFish-Corba
(2) JBoss repackaging of the OpenJDK ORB
```

JDK7 uses CORBA 2.3.1 .
GlassFish ORB complies with the CORBA 2.3.1 specification.
But there is no specific CORBA description for JBoss repackaging of the OpenJDK ORB. Is it the same as in the JDK?

Comment: If you're looking for a standalone ORB, you might try JacORB (https://www.jacorb.org/). I've been using it in CORBA projects for... more years than I care to admit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is CORBA of JBoss OpenJDK ORB same as in JDK?

The answer to your question is Yes.

The JBoss OpenJDK ORB is described as a "downstream fork" of the OpenJDK ORB.  The differences are minimal<sup>1</sup>.

Note that official OpenJDK CORBA didn't move past CORBA 2.3.1 (which was only a minor editorial revision of 2.3).  There are other CORBA vendors, but I haven't been able to find any that claim to fully implement later versions of the CORBA specs.

---

<sup>1 - If you need to, you can grab the respective source code trees from git and use `diff -r` to compare them.</sup>